# Can it damage a CPU to only stress out a single core?

Tags: cpu, stress-test

Damage is meant as a broad term here. Could any negative effects occur if I run a 100% workload on a single core in a multicore CPU?

The thought has two sources.

1. is the temperature difference between the cores. It may be the case that the heat spreads so well over the heatspreader that this has no effect, I don't know.
2. is the fear of breaking a core in the CPU (and thereby breaking the whole CPU) due to the long time (potentially 24/7) workload on it. Should I switch which cores I stress on a daily basis to prevent this?

In practice, I'm using Handbrake to transcode lots of old videos, and it fills all CPU cores with 100% load immediately, so I restrict it to use only 1-3 of my 6 cores, so that I can still use my PC normally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I burn a single core in a multicore CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/1747298/can-i-burn-a-single-core-in-a-multicore-cpu)